# Makefile error - unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: bash, makefile, cp

An excerpt of my Makefile is as follows:

```
.PHONY: product1 product2 product3
product1 product2 product3:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEPRGFLAGS) -C $(LIBS_ROOT)/$@
    cp -r `ls -A | grep ".*\.a$"` $(PROJECT_PATH)/lib/ $(PRODUCT_PATH)/
```

After the compilation is done, when it tries to copy the `.a` files, it gives me this error:

> /bin/sh: command substitution: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking
>   for matching `"'
>
> /bin/sh: command substitution: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of
>   file

I have taken care to provide the matching braces. What is wrong in my Makefile declaration?

I am running on cygwin in Windows. Editing Makefiles from Notepad++ with EOL conversion as windows format.

Answer (score 7):

`$` has special meaning in makefiles. If you want to use it in a shell command, you have to double it.

```
product1 product2 product3:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEPRGFLAGS) -C $(LIBS_ROOT)/$@
    cp -r `ls -A | grep ".*\.a$$"` $(PROJECT_PATH)/lib/ $(PRODUCT_PATH)/
```

But instead of using `ls` and `grep`, you could just give wildcards to `ls`:

```
    cp -r *.a .*.a $(PROJECT_PATH)/lib/ $(PRODUCT_PATH)/
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf True. You can enable `nullglob` to prevent that. If neither of them matches, neither syntax will work correctly.